# Get Request Referer in Ruby on Rails after page refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, referer

My problem is to get referer after page refresh. I need to find out if the user does not reloaded page. In my `articles_controller` i check before `article.views_count` increment

```
def increment(article)  
  if request.referer != article_url(article)
    # increment code
  end
end
```

but `request.referer` returns url, that was before reload and after each page refresh method  increment is running

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try:

```
def increment(article)  
  if request.referer != request.original_url
    # increment code
  end
end
```

Comment: Problem is in request.referrer, but not in article_path. This renurns the same

Comment: ok, I've got it. You could write current referrer to user's session, then if `request.referrer != session[:referrer]` increment views